# how to run my all test cases on every developer build automatically?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I just want to know something about Katalon Studio. I have not worked in automation testing before but now I have some assignment about testing in Katalon.

My client wants to test in Katalon but his requirement is that he wants to run test cases on every build automatically and he also doesn't want to install Katalon IDE or any library he just want reference so that he just added that reference on every build so that all the test cases run automatically on every Dev build.

Is this possible using Katalon? Kindly help me, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to establish full CI Pipeline for your requirements. My advice is, to use Katalon with Jenkins and your developers code repository (perhaps GIT or SVN). Than you are able to implement a server/slave pipeline, where you can execute your Katalon scripts on slave, every time DEV builds.
See: 
[Katalon/Jenkins Tutorial](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/videos/integration_jenkins_ci.html)